# Craft CMS contact form plugin works locally but not in production?

Tags: plugins, craft3, plugin-contactform

Locally in a MAMP environment Craft CMS/Contact Form plugin works great! But for some reason in production on a actual live server on the internet it fails to successfully send any emails.

I'm not sure if this is because of the way email is handled by Craft? In Settings > Email, I set the transport type up to Gmail instead of the default Sendmail. But still no luck.

Comment: If you test your email settings in /admin/settings/email (`test` button at the bottom of the page), what message do you get, and does that test email arrive?

Comment: Successful. Just doesn't arrive. Looks like I may need to go the mailgun route

Comment: Mailgun, Postmark, Mandrill ... With the advantage of clearer error message and status reports :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a support article here you can help use to debug email deliver issues: https://craftcms.com/support/troubleshooting-email-errors#dealing-with-email-delivery-issues

The TL/DR is, use a transaction email provider like Postmark, Mailgun, etc. and make sure you've got DKIM/SPF and DMARC all setup properly as well.